# Angular 12 using inline scss

Tags: angular, angular12

I have just updated to Angular 12 and I would like to try out one of the new features which is inline scss / sass

I can see it's enabled in my angular.json:

```
"inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
```

I'm looking for an example on how to do inline scss as it's something I've never done before but cannot find any examples online.

How do I use the inline sass feature in Angular 12?

Comment: If you get here and are wondering where in your `angular.json` to enable this, `"inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"` goes under `projects -> project -> architect -> build -> options` and `projects -> project -> architect -> test -> options`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inline scss it means that now you can use scss in styles field of @Component decorator. Previously, Sass was only available in external resources (a separate scss file along with the component) due to the Angular compiler.

Ex:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],

  // Possible for scss from angular 12
  styles: [
    `
    span {
      color: grey;
    }
    `
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular12 app';
}
```

Style is applied and added to the style tag in browser:-

[image]

Comment: Ohhhh!!! OK....I thought I could use inline variables from my scss files :( It would have made it really easy to change / create themes...but anyway now I know that's it's about :)